# Hacer un sp y un job en sql, que genere un archivo csv, en un directorio x

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedure, jobs

Teniendo en cuenta, que estoy armando un query en procesos almacenados, creo, que ya tengo el query, pero he buscado en internet la sentencia u orden para exporat el query en un archivo .csv. Y unos fotosme dicen que msbk, otros bcp, no entiendo bien, exportar el archivo cn la consulta, ya realizada.

```
Este es mi SP

USE [BdName]
GO 
/*** Consultar campos de uan tabla y exportarlos en un archivo .csv en un 
directorio x****/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE sp_reports_users  
AS 
BEGIN 
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    declare @id int
    declare @campo1 varchar(100)
    declare @campo2 varchar(25)
    declare @campo3 varchar(15)

    --Consulta a la dbo
     Select @id, @campo1, @campo2, @campo3 From dbo.tabla

EXE sp_reports_users;
```

quisiera saber que mas prosigue o una guia mas o menos para seguir adelante. muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Por qué usas variables en vez de columnas de la tabla?

Comment: @LuisCazares Disculpa mi ignorancia, pense, que se declaraban asi los campos, antes de llamarlos al query, corrigueme por favor

Answer (score 2):

puedes hacerlo asi:

## con sqlcmd

```
sqlcmd -S serveName -i miscript.sql  -o salida_a_csv.csv -W -w 1024 -s","
```

- -S = nombre del servidor en `cmd` con `hostname`lo consigues
- -i =  nombre del archivo sql
- -o  = nombre del archivo
- -W  = remover espacios finales
- -w  = tama;o del las columnas
- -s = separador de columnas

## con bcp

```
bcp -i miscript.sql queryout salida_a_csv.csv -S servername -c -t"," -T
```

[image: bcp comandos]

Comment: Añadiendo la opción de hacerlo con SSIS o SSRS, quedaría excelente la respuesta.

Comment: @Bryro Pero como seria con mi ejemplo de arriba y los campos, estoy intentando hacerlo asi y no me funciona con "bcp" por favor